# Responsive, single button input in A-Frame WebVR

Tags: aframe, webvr, gamecontroller

For my A-Frame WebVR game, I need to access a single "controller" button, regardless of platform. For a phone using a magic window or Google Cardboard, any screen tap would count.  For Gear VR or Daydream, any button on the controller would count. For a PC VR rig, any button on either controller would count.

Don McCurdy's universal-controls (https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls) would seem to be relevant, yet it's not clear how I could use it to do what I want.

I could also go access the GamePad API directly, and separately detect screen taps.

What's the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the input mapping system, from Fernando Serrano could help:
https://blog.mozvr.com/input-mapping/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, if you want to treat all buttons alike, it's easier to listen for the buttonchanged event on the controls entity.

As Noam kindly pointed out, aframe-input-mapping-component is great for general mapping of buttons to actions.

[edit] I've created [aframe-button-controls](https://github.com/DougReeder/aframe-button-controls) to handle this.